# sql server add a row with same records except for ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code is as below"

```
select * into tbltemp
       from table1 where ID='12345'

               update tbltemp set ID='54321'where ID='12345'


         insert into table1 
               select * from tbltemp where ID='54321'

    drop table tbltemp
```

When executing insert into query, I got error saying 'Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.'

I wonder how I can deal with that?

My table1 has 50 columns with three computed columns.

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

`table1` and `tbltemp` must match by number of columns. You must explicitly name the columns do not use the `*` sign in insert into from select, if number of columns do not match.

Comment: I think my number of columns did match. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that when I have computed columns, the query doesn't work well.
So I delete the computed columns before copy a new one, then do an insert into select *, then add computed columns back, in this way I can save the time for writing 50 fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a computed column. You need to select especific fields in select and in value() statements. No select *